# What's the character limit of this text field?

Tags: code-golf, math, parsing

Someone I know has no coding experience, but has proposed an algorithm* to determine the character limit of text fields they find online. They copy a string containing the numbers from 1 to 1,000 inclusive, not separated in any way, and they read the last few digits it displays.

For example, after pasting, they might see

`...5645745845`

From here, they can figure out the character limit.

They've got two problems with this approach. One, it's a little hard to determine where the discrete numbers are in the string. (The last whole number displayed here is `458`, and the final two digits would have been followed by `9` if the text field allowed one more character.)

Two, the math is a little tricky even when that character has been identified. It's easy with single digits. For instance, if the last whole number were `5`, the limit would be `5` characters. With double digits it's a little harder. If the last whole number were `13` followed by the `1` of `14`, the full field would display `123456789101112131` for a limit of `18` characters.

They've managed to get a script that copies the last 10 digits the text field displays, or as many as the field holds if the field can hold less than 10. They'd like to feed that into another script that returns the field's length limit.

Additional test cases:

```
'' -> 0
'1' -> 1
'12' -> 2
'7891011121' -> 16
'1191201211' -> 256
'5645745845' -> 1268
```

Here are some examples of invalid inputs, incidentally:

```
'0'
'121'
'1211'
```

---

* Possibly in jest :)

Comment: Since this can by computed by a "generate everything and find the input" strategy, a harder variation might allow inputs to be arbitrarily large, and guarantee only that you are given enough digits to uniquely find it, assuming the input is the first instance of that sequence in the nats.

Comment: @Jonah Good call. After all, the "find input in string" strategy is probably how I'd do it. Do you think it's too late to change with an update given the 7 answers, or is it worth improving now? Not sure of Code Golf conventions.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I think it would need to be a part 2 post

Comment: What makes you say `5645745845` is not `564574584` with the end of `5645745846`?
I think you need to give certain boundaries to the text field calculation.

Comment: @P.b I don't follow. If we're dealing with consecutive natural numbers from 1 to 1,000, the only valid sequence I see is `...(4)56,457,458,4(59)...` Here's how I reason: we can't be in the single digits, because `4,6` isn't valid. We can't be in the double digits, because neither `56,45` nor `64,57` is valid. So we must be in the triple digits. It can't be `564,574` or `645,745`, so it must be `457,458`. However, that does give me an interesting idea for a variation of the problem: rather than knowing the numbers are consecutive, the step could be any power of `10` up to the column value...

Comment: I missed on the 1 to 1000 part and got mislead by the example being larger than 1000 in the first place.

Comment: People finding improvements to a challenge is part of the reason for "it is highly recommended to first post proposed challenges in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc)."!

Comment: Needs more test cases IMO

Comment: @Joao-3 Maybe so; do you have an edge case in mind that's not covered by the existing tests?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Maybe an implementation fails the edge case "0" (11)?

Comment: @Joao-3 That is not a valid input. I added some more valid ones, though.

Comment: @LukeSawczak "8091011121" is invalid; use "7891011121" instead

Comment: @Joao-3 Whoops, you're right! I was busily padding everything to two digits due to ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ brain problems...

Comment: @LukeSawczak Also, "1191201211" should return 256, not 230.

Comment: @Joao-3 Yes indeed. Thanks

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66878/find-the-number-in-the-champernowne-constant)

Answer (score 6):

## Excel (ms365)

**1)** Recursion with `LAMBDA()`, **74 bytes**:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(x,LAMBDA(y,n,s,IFERROR(FIND(A1,s),y(y,n+1,s&n))),x(x,1,""))+LEN(A1)-1
```

**Note**: Due to the limitations within Excel this may return an error above a certain amount of recursive lambda calls.

---

**2)** Concatenating with `ROW()`, **39 bytes**:

I did explicitly want to stay away from using a concatenated string from any arbitrary range of numbers for this challenge. If one is okay with this concept then try:

```
 =FIND(A1,CONCAT(ROW(1:8468)))+LEN(A1)-1
```

Here I found that concatenating `ROW(1:8468)` seems to be Excel's (or rather `CONCAT()`'s) limit.

---

**3)** Overcome Excel's limits using `PY()`, **87 bytes**:

To overcome these limits of function within Excel, we could use the new `PY()` function:

```
=PY(
    ''.join(map(str,range(1,int(xl("A1")+1)))).find(str(xl("A1")))++len(str(xl("A1")))
)
```

**Note**: Python is not my forté, so I'm sure this can be golfed down. However, more importantly. Since `PY()` is executed on an external server there is a high chance of this code error out due to a "time-limit".

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 50 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 6.25 bytes

```
⌊ɾṅḟ?L+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oyKyb7huYXhuJ8/TCsiLCIiLCJcIjEwMTExMlwiIl0=)

Bitstring:

```
11001011010011010000000111000101111000110100000010
```

Times out for very large inputs because it needs to generate a range between 1 and whatever number represented by the input.

### Explained

```
⌊ɾṅḟ?L+­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
⌊ɾ       # ‎⁡The range [1, input]
  ṅ      # ‎⁢Joined into a single string.
   ḟ     # ‎⁣Find the index of the input in that string
    ?L+  # ‎⁤And add the length of the input to that
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: It’s a little misleading for the link in the header to go to the default branch, since this is Vyxal 2

Comment: @noodleman never attribute to malice what can adequately be explained by stupidity (ie forgetting to update the template generator)

Comment: never attribute to malice what can adequately be explained by stupidity (ie using the word “misleading” instead of “confusing”) :p

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 43 bytes

```javascript
x=>~(g=s=>~s.indexOf(x,1)||g(s+i++))(x,i=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q5OI922GEgV62XmpaRW@KdpVOgYatbUpGsUa2dqa2tqAvmZtoaa/625kvPzivNzUvVy8tM10jTUzcwtLA0NDA0NjdQ1NTFk4ZKG2GRNzUxMzU1MLUxMscli1QIS@w8A)

Using range, fail `11` (expect 13, get 1)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 49 bytes

```javascript
x=>~(g=s=>~s.search(x)||g(s+ ++i))(i='')+x.length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcvBCgIhFIXhfU/RznuRJENnJsLeRcxxjEFj7hAuhl7datMmVwf@j3O3T0tuiY/1kPLN19HUYq4vCIY@Q4K8XdwEBbctAPE95xERomEMeRGzT2Gd6mXncqI8ezHnACOwrh/O8iilPDHEP/2hbKnulO6VHpRuafPybfUN)

-4 from Arnauld

Not using the 10

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##bcuxDsIgFEDR3a9w470QiRhoq4b6LQQpxRIwpTFM/jrGxUXWe3If@qWzWf1zO8R0t3VStagRnMpqfMOiMstWr2aGgnhbaGHBRrfNFweZ7in1iOAVIVivO5NiTsGykBxMQLp@OPMj5/xEEP/0h7ylshOyF3IQsqXN5dvqBw)?

Comment: @Arnauld Is [this](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1q5OI922GEgV62XmpaRW@KdpVOgYatbUpGsUa2dqa2tqAvmZtoaa/625kvPzivNzUvVy8tM10jTUzcwtLA0NDA0NjdQ1NTFk4ZKG2GRNzUxMzU1MLUxMscli1QIS@w8A) correct?

Comment: Yes, that looks safe.

Comment: How does this work? Does it also use brute force, like most other answers?

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LJIkIg+
```

Times out for larger inputs. Add a leading `₄` (push 1000) to speed it up.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx8sz2zNd@/9/U3MTUwsTUwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/H6/K7Mp07f86/6MNdZSUdEx1DI0NdUzNTUwtTExjAQ).

**Explanation:**

```python
L        # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 J       # Join it together to a single string
  Ik     # Pop and push the (0-based) index of the input
    Ig+  # Add the length of the input
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>34</s>  30 bytes

```ruby
->i{[*1..1e3]*''=~/(?<=#{i})/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc5LCoMwFIXheVZx0UFUasw1D3OhsQspHbRFISClSDsoYreejpOOv5/DWd@3T5x9bMewnRsUAid1aTj33646HX25hb3u9vhcw@MFs7hfl6UCjhzqQ8EKKKEdAVnGicpcjdVm0MZpk6701uUp9knS507kiAillGnnSP1PKW3s4Cj7LhnEHw)

*Thanks to @Neil for saving 1 Byte by removing useless + in regexp*

Regexp /(?<=#{i})+/ finds index next to input in the constructed string `[*1..1e3]*''` by using a look behind.

Comment: I don't think you need the `+` do you?

Comment: @Neil well.. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-p`), 27 bytes

```perl
(join"",1..1e3)=~$_;$_="@+"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18jKz8zT0lJx1BPzzDVWNO2TiXeWiXeVslBW@n/fzNzC0tDA0NDQyMuOMuQy9TMxNTcxNTCxJTLkIvrX35BSWZ@XvF/3ZwCAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>65</s> 63 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [@AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84844/aztecco)*

```hs
n%h|l<-length n,n==take l h=l
n%(_:h)=1+n%h
f=(%([1..]>>=show))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcvdCoIwGAbg813FiyBsZNHMmUVfNyISI2YT14w26KR7XxbS2cP7Y3UYjXMp@dy@3WntjL9FC194oqhHAwdLjvmcX45WkFzNO9YTz3krN5vufKZgp5cQ6a4HD8LjOfiItscAIkx4gw8FJoHTGtGEeNXBhI6xv@dPywCeyayAFMXPM7cLVV2pfaWaSn37sm6WXJa7StX75vD7bUXH0gc)

Comment: [63](https://tio.run/##PcvdCoIwGAbg813FiyBsZNHMmUVfNyISI2YT14w26KR7XxbS2cP7Y3UYjXMp@dy@3WntjL9FC194oqhHAwdLjvmcX45WkFzNO9YTz3krN5vufKZgp5cQ6a4HD8LjOfiItscAIkx4gw8FJoHTGtGEeNXBhI6xv@dPywCeyayAFMXPM7cLVV2pfaWaSn37sm6WXJa7StX75vD7bUXH0gc "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 38 bytes

```
^
1001$*1¶
\G1
$.`
r`\B\1.*¶(.*)
$1
\B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wP47L0MDAUEXL8NA2rhh3Qy4VvQSuooQYpxhDPa1D2zT0tDS5VAy5Ypz@/@cy5DIEITA2BAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
^
1001$*1¶
\G1
$.`
```

Create a string of all the numbers from `0` to `1000` concatenated.

```
r`\B\1.*¶(.*)
$1
```

Remove everything after the first copy of the input, but don't delete the leading `0`. The `r` reverses the direction of processing, so the `(.*)` is matched first and the `\B` last.

```
\B
```

Count the pairs of adjacent digits, which is the same as the length excluding the leading `0`.

Alternative 38-byte version that works for arbitrary numbers given enough memory and processing power but is slower for inputs of four or more digits.

```
^
$'$*111¶
\G1
$.`
r`\B\1.*¶(.*)
$1
\B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wP45LRV1Fy9DQ8NA2rhh3Qy4VvQSuooQYpxhDPa1D2zT0tDS5VAy5Ypz@/@cy5DIEITA2BAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
^
$'$*111¶
\G1
$.`
```

Create a string of all the numbers from `0` to the input plus `1` concatenated. (This is needed for the edge case of an empty input.)

```
r`\B\1.*¶(.*)
$1
```

Remove everything after the first copy of the input, but don't delete the leading `0`.

```
\B
```

Take the length excluding the leading `0`.

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, <s>35</s> 33 bytes

Two bytes saved thanks to Tbw

Prompts for string of digits:

```
↑(¯1+⍴s)+((s←,⎕)⍷n)/⍳⍴n←⊃,/⍕¨⍳1E3
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3t/6O2iRqH1htqP@rdUqypraFRDJTSAarRfNS7PU9T/1HvZqBMHlDwUVezDpA79dAKoJihq/F/oHau/2lc6obqXEASTJiamZiam5hamJiCuYZGxiamZuYWloYGhoaGRobGEKWGQIqLCwA)

Comment: You can save bytes with `⊃,/⍕¨⍳1E3` to make the string.

Comment: @Tbw Thanks. Edited code.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 10 bytes

Semi-port of [lyxal's Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267362)

```
J1,a~:Xa$)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuharvAx1EuusIhJVNCECUPFl0YYGhoaxUB4A)

```
J1,a~:Xa$)­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
J1,a        # ‎⁡Range from 1 to input as string
    ~:Xa    # ‎⁢Match input as regex in range
        $)  # ‎⁣Return last index of first match
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: If you switch the operands to `~`, you can get rid of the `:`. (In the upcoming version 1.2, you'll be able to drop the `X` as well.)

Comment: @DLosc new version?? :D I’ll update my answers later this month, I can’t right now

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
Ｉ⁺Ｌθ⌕⭆φ⊕ιθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrRCkAwFADQX/F4V9TUhvKolKKUL1izWM3FXH7/2nk@djfRniYwz9EjQWcegjm8D4wON9rhFnnWe1xhoRS2yVxQSinzbEAb3eGQ3ApepHWLpGXWldK10o3SXHzhBw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
      φ     Predefined variable `1000`
     ⭆      Map over implicit range and join
        ι   Current value
       ⊕    Incremented
    ⌕       Find index of
         θ  Input string
 ⁺          Plus
   θ        Input string
  Ｌ         Length
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes

```apl
≢-1-(⊃∘⍸⍷∘(⊃,/⍕¨⍳1E3))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/TeFR2wSFR52LdA11NR51NT/qmPGod8ej3u1ABoivo/@od@qhFY96Nxu6Gmtq/v9fklpcUgzWpK6uoG4IwkbGJqZm5haWII6pmYmpuYmphYkpkGNpaGBoaGhkaAySsbS0sLQEihgYqHNxgU3RiTbUM41NO7QCYqbCo965Cmn5RbmJJSWZeekA)

```apl
≢-1-(⊃∘⍸⍷∘(⊃,/⍕¨⍳1E3))  # tacit function⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
     ⊃∘⍸⍷∘               # ‎⁡index of first subsequence equal to input in 
                 1E3    # ‎⁢⁡1000 
                ⍳       # ‎⁤range 
              ⍕¨       # ‎⁣toString each 
            ,/          # ‎⁢concat reduce 
          ⊃,/⍕¨⍳1E3    # '12345678910...'
 -1-                    # ‎⁢⁢minus 1 (because a-1-c = a-(1-c) = ¯1+a+c in APL)
≢                       # ‎⁢⁣length of input (this is one character;
                     # the code block does not display it correctly)
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 55 bytes

```
lambda s:"".join(map(str,range(1,1001))).find(s)+len(s)
```

This is a rather simple solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
+A³õ ¬
aN
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=K0Gz9SCsCmFO&input=IjU2NDU3NDU4NDUi)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 57 bytes

```javascript
x=>[...Array(1000).keys()].join('').indexOf(x)-1+x.length
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5NDoIwEEb3nKJhQxtl0kEQCMHEhWsPYFwYbfGHtAnUBC7gJdyw0IVH8jZCwUwyk-9l5mWeL6VPovuUwhBJckLfdyP95Js2-WoHAOuqOrQUOecMbqKtKdvDVV8U9TwGF3USzVbShvk4a6AUqjDnSfBgmTNIjahN3Yt3boocEQNcoDsnbrQMoziMkjAakkUY2I4pBrzfsyxO_mfuPnOsDKSuNofjmVo3yVfkqFWtSwGlLiiRE2dDZeM3XTfOHw)

Constructs `"0123456789..."`, then finds the input in it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```scala
s=>(1 to 1000).mkString.indexOf(s)+s.size
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lZK7asMwFIaho5_i4EmixLETO7ENDnTs0Au0nUIKjiM7ah3JWMekF_IkXbK0S58ofZo6UaEemoImIfH93znS0duHytIyHX5O7Z6Q67QW9mx3L-cPLEO4SLmAVwtgwXJYtRuS1oWK4ayu0-fpDdZcFDMaw53gCMmB1GzOxeJaKo5cihiIJpPJuUDacu8N5r1wR1UyIR6gBM91XeqsHjXntGH2dJUTRU-Vo_gL04Gvk8u9v2oZLAXp1iC2Z1MK_T7cLhnIBqsGYc3LEuYMsD2qfkCQObQsVGWjgKOCkokCl9Zx8XGvC0RxkekC2nPQ28AVuPQfZzDyg7EfhH5g0HUnZNC-NzB5mIGJOorCKIr2szMo0QkZ3WLoB6NxGBmN-Tf0R6mNtdHfarvV6zc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 30 bytes

```
(⊏0+⧻:⊚⌕:/$"__"+1⇡1e3.|0;)=0⧻.
```

[Test suite](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__RiDihpAgKOKKjzAr4qe7OuKKmuKMlTovJCJfXyIrMeKHoTFlMy58MDspPTDip7suCgpGICIiCkYgIjEiCkYgIjEyIgpGICI3ODkxMDExMTIxIgpGICIxMTkxMjAxMjExIgpGICI1NjQ1NzQ1ODQ1Igo=)

I felt like adding another answer